# How to add 2 looped list with while or for

Tags: python-3.x

Very Simple.
I want to add two lists with while or for in python3. so when writing the letter a the 1 appears and when writing the letter b the 2 appears and when writing the letter c the c is printed. Thanks in advance

```
            x = input()

            letter = ["a","b","c"]

            number = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: This isn't exactly "adding", but what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

I had a little trouble understanding the question, particularly this part:

> "and when writing the letter c the c is printed"

I *think* you meant that you wanted 3 printed if the person types in c.

Here is some code that does that:

```
letter = ['a', 'b', 'c']
number = [1, 2, 3]
x = input("Please type a, b, or c > ")
if x in letter:
    for index, value in enumerate(letter):
        if x == value:
            print(number[index])
else:
    print("The value you typed is not in my list")
```

Comment: Note: I wouldn't choose personally to solve this with a `for` loop, but this is what the question asked for. Something like `print(number[letter.index(x)])` seems more efficient.